# How to get multi monitor orientations

Tags: delphi

Delphi 6.
Windows 10.

The default InputQuery opens in the center of the main form.
I'm creating my own InputQuery that will open in the center of the calling form.

It almost works.

The problem is that on monitors that are rotated 90 degrees to get portrait  mode,
the screen height and width are returned as if the monitor was still in landscape mode.

I tried:
- Setting Position to poOwnerFormCenter, worked but always ended up on the primary monitor.
- Calculating Form.Left and Form.Right, worked, on the correct monitor, but X and Y swapped.
This failed when screen height and width properties were always swapped.

Not being able to figure out how to resolve that,
I decided to swap height and width when in portrait mode.

On a forum I found and modified a function to read monitor data
hoping to be able to determine which mode the monitor is in.
I cannot make that work either,
nor have I been able to identify the monitor (I have 4, 3 in portrait mode) that call my function.

The data returned by EnumDisplaySettings is always,
regardless of monitor:
- Height      = 640
- Width       = 480
- Orientation = 0

Can someone see what I do wrong?
The AddToLog procedure displays the strings in a memo.
Code as follows:

```
procedure TXIO_Configurator_form.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lpDisplayDevice: TDisplayDevice;
  dwFlags        : DWORD;
  cc             : DWORD;
  DevMode        : TDeviceMode;
  S              : string;
begin
  lpdisplaydevice.cb := sizeof(lpdisplaydevice);
  dwflags := 0;
  cc:= 0;

while EnumDisplayDevices(nil, cc, lpDisplayDevice , dwFlags) do
  begin  
    EnumDisplaySettings(lpDisplayDevice.DeviceName, 0, DevMode);

    S := 'Height = ' + IntToStr(DevMode.dmPelsHeight);    // Always 640
    MainForm.AddToActivityLog(S, False);

    S := 'Width  = ' + IntToStr(DevMode.dmPelsWidth);     // Always 480  
    MainForm.AddToActivityLog(S, False);

    S := 'Orient = ' + IntToStr(DevMode.dmOrientation);   // Always 0  
    MainForm.AddToActivityLog(S, False);


    inc(cc);
  end;
```

Comment: poOwnerFormCenter should work. Are you sure you are actually specifying the owner? (`frm := TMyForm.Create(Self); try frm.ShowModal; finally frm.Free; end;` Here `Self` is the owner form.)

Comment: Don't have D6 but I cannot reproduce this with D7. AFAIR multi-monitor support was added with D4. Self.Monitor.Width|Height works as expected where Self is a form instance. VCL calls MonitorFromWindow to get a handle of the monitor that the form is on, then calls  GetMonitorInfo with that handle.

Comment: Andreas Rejbrand, you nailed it. I had specified "Application" as the owner, as it was done in th original code I found and modified. I did not realize my situation was different. It works perfectly now. Thanks. If you change your comment to an "answer" I'll be happy to accept it as a solution. @Sertac Akyuz, thanks for confirming that this works, if done properly.

Comment: Well, owner error does not explain switched width, height... but I guess who cares...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let my offer a solution to your actual problem.

> I tried:
>   - Setting Position to poOwnerFormCenter, worked but always ended up on the primary monitor.

Well, `poOwnerFormCenter` should work. But you must specify the owner.

For instance,

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  dlg: TMyDialog;
begin
  dlg := TMyDialog.Create(Self);
  try
    dlg.ShowModal;
  finally
    dlg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The owner is passed as the argument of the constructor, in this case `Self`. This is the "owner" referred to in "owner form center".